# Show only whatsapp while sharing image using UIDocumentInteractionController

Tags: ios, whatsapp, uidocumentinteraction

According to the documentation https://www.whatsapp.com/faq/en/iphone/23559013, setting file format to .wai and UTI to net.whatsapp.image will only show Whatsapp in application list,

But its showing other application like Add to notes,messenger also along with whatsapp option.

```
    if let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0)
    { 
        let path = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSSearchPathDirectory.DocumentDirectory, NSSearchPathDomainMask.UserDomainMask, true)
        let documentsDir: AnyObject = path[0]
        let imagePath = documentsDir.stringByAppendingPathComponent("Main")

        NSFileManager.defaultManager().createDirectoryAtPath(imagePath, withIntermediateDirectories: true, attributes: nil)

        let tempFile = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: imagePath+"/image.wai")
        do
        {
            try imageData.writeToURL(tempFile, options: .DataWritingAtomic)
            self.documentController = UIDocumentInteractionController(URL: tempFile)
            self.documentController.UTI = "net.whatsapp.image"
            self.documentController.presentOpenInMenuFromRect(self.view.frame, inView: self.view, animated: true)
        }
        catch
        {
            // alert

        }
    }
```

Please suggest if i am doing something wrong here

Comment: Did you find any solution?